# Facebook Messenger API line break JSON error

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

A bit new to JSON, but I understand the basics...  I have a system that integrates with the Facebook Messenger API and the Webhook page simply dumps the data into my MySql database so I can process the data on my system.  Everything works normally until a user sends a message with a line break.  I can't post all my code, but here is the basics :

My_Webhook_File.php

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($input, true);
$sender = $data['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
$message = $data['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];
$message_id = $data['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['mid'];
$recipient = $data['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['recipient']['id'];

if(!empty($sender)){
     $db = db("INSERT INTO FB (senderid, sender_name, recipient, the_time, data, is_read) VALUES ('".numbersonly($sender)."', '".$fbname."', '".$recipient."', NOW(), '".json_encode($data)."', '".$is_read."')");
}
```

Everything works normally until a user sends text with a new line (SHIFT + ENTER) directly from FB.  I have tried dumping only the contents of "$input" into the database and still get the same result.  How would I fix this issue?  I tried nl2br which did not work at all.

Example of what is returned :

```
{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"MY_PAGE_ID","time":1672599591761,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"SENDER_ID"},"recipient":{"id":"RECIPIENT_ID"},"timestamp":1672599591554,"message":{"mid":"MESSAGE_ID","text":"maybe
this
will

work"}}],"hop_context":[{"app_id":MY_APP_ID,"metadata":""}]}]}
```

How it should look :

```
{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"MY_PAGE_ID","time":1672599591761,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"SENDER_ID"},"recipient":{"id":"RECIPIENT_ID"},"timestamp":1672599591554,"message":{"mid":"MESSAGE_ID","text":"maybe\nthis\nwill\nwork"}}],"hop_context":[{"app_id":MY_APP_ID,"metadata":""}]}]}
```

Comment: What JSON error do you get? What is the problem?

Comment: @WizKid at the bottom of the post, you can see where there are line breaks in the returned message.  Because it is no longer valid JSON, it returns NULL when attempting to parse the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

So after loads of researching, I figured a work around.  Here is the updated method.

I set the SQL Column "data" to a Text type instead of JSON and then used str_replace() to fix the extra lines.  There may be a cleaner method to this, but it seems to be working :)

```
<?php
// $message['data'] is directly from the DB

// replace all carriage returns with ":linebreak" to avoid converting <br /> in htmlentities 
$data = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), ':linebreak:', $message['data']);
$m = json_decode($data);
if(is_array($m->entry[0]->messaging[0]->message->attachments ?? null)){
    foreach($m->entry[0]->messaging[0]->message->attachments as $obj){
        if($obj->type == "image"){
?>
            <a href="<?php echo $obj->payload->url;?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $obj->payload->url;?>" width="100%"></a><br />
<?php
        }
    }
}
// clean up any potential HTML code the user may have sent or characters that can affect the output
$parsed_data = htmlentities(stripslashes($m->entry[0]->messaging[0]->message->text));
// now that htmlentities is done, replace ":linebreak:" with <br />
$data = str_replace(':linebreak:', '<br />', $parsed_data);
echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: You were pretty fast on closing: It's fine when you see multiple of them in the process manager: the script is written that it waits when there is a lock, so you should see one or two of that script in the process list.